# Reading specific values from a file

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file in which there is some data and then followed by lines of values. I need to retrieve only those lines where there is a set of two integers, four floats followed by a integer separated by a space. Can anyone please help me how to recognize only such lines and retrieve data from it?

Comment: I think you should put this text as formatted text within your question.

Comment: @GopalSamant: It would be useful if you edit your original post and put this information over there :)

Comment: Just paste the text as it is formatted in your file, then, you should notice an icon with curly braces: **{}**. Just highlight the text in the file and press that icon, your text should now be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you mention your problem it *seems* that you already have a pattern. Using a regular expression such as `^\d+ \d+ \d+(\.\d+)? \d+(\.\d+)? \d+(\.\d+)? \d+(\.\d+)? \d+$` should match text like so: `23 24 1.2 3.6 9.1 5.0 4`.

So you could traverse your file one line at a time and use a pattern like the above to see if you have the line you want. I am assuming that you do not have other lines with the same pattern and that you do not want to match negative numbers.